# jsonParser.makeHttpRequest how to send and receive data

Tags: java, android, json

So I know(some what) how to send and receive data with jsonParser.makeHttpRequest as different requests, but what if I want to send data to the server and then based on the data send the server will respond and send data back? Would I send it like:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
```

and then get it like:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
```

Right after each other both to the same url?

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

EDIT1:
I want to send to the server the date,longitude and latitude. Then based on that the server will send back data that will populate a list.

Comment: Could you specify the use case please. What is the requested Service?

Comment: just trying to connect to a WAMP server on my computer. I have got it to work separately(as in send data to server to save and request saved data) But would I send data which the server looks at and determines what to send back.

Comment: I added a little edit to be more specific.